# Starting Symfony 4 development Server does not work

Tags: php, symfony, class, controller

When trying to start the development server under Symfony 4
(i.e. php bin/console server start), I get the following error:

The autoloader expected class

> "App\Hs\LuckyNumberBundle\Controller\LuckyNumberController" to be
> defined in file "/home/rainermusik/musikdb/vendor/composer/../..
> /src/Hs/LuckyNumberBundle/Controller/LuckyNumberController.php".

The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

the controller-class in question is defined as follows:

```
// src/Controller/LuckyNumberController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class LuckyNumberController extends Controller
{
    public function number()
    {
        $number = mt_rand(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

I can't see what I am doing that's incorrect.

Comment: Are you trying to create a bundle for some reason?  The error message implies you have your controller under /src/Hs/LuckyNumberBundle/Controller.  It should just be under src/Controller.  But if you really want a bundle then change the namespace in your controller file to reflect that.

Comment: how does your config/service.yml file looks? The path you have mentioned there need to match with the path your controller is at.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! Having come from Symfony 3, I DID in fact want to create a bundle. Considering the (at the moment!) limited scope of the application (mainly learning!), I have abandoned the bundle idea. Things work now...